# How to implement distributed algorithm of leader election using JBotsim library

Tags: java, lib, distributed-algorithm, leader-election

i am trying to implement two Distributed algorithms of leader election using JBotSim lib but i don't have no idea this lib or how does it operate
someone can help me or have any example about it?

Comment: There are many [examples](https://jbotsim.io/?p=examples/) located under the **examples** tab on the [jbotsim homepage](https://jbotsim.io/).

Comment: Thanks a lot friend,  but i need a example of distibuted algorithm for leader election  how use this lib???

Comment: I wish I could give more insight but I have no experience with the algorithm or jbotsim. However, I found this repo on github: [leader-election-jbotsim](https://github.com/haritzmedina/leader-election-jbotsim) .

Comment: thank's a lot friend